# Scipy Optimise (minimize) not giving correct results

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, constraints, minimize

I am trying to do a simple minimisation as below using SciPy optimise, but the expected results are NOT matching the optimiser output:

```
x0 = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4]
x_expected = np.array([0., 0., 0., 1])
bounds = ((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1))
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'t1': [1, 2, 3, 2, 1], 't2': [3, 4, 5, 6, 2], 't3': [2, 3, 2, 3, 5], 'c': [1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4]}).to_numpy()

    factors = pd.DataFrame(
        {"tk": ["t1", "t2", "t3", "c"], "class": ["x", "y", "x", "z"]})
    min_max_class = pd.DataFrame(
        {"class": ["x", "y", "z"], "min_allocation": [0., 0., 0.], "max_allocation": [0.0001, 0.5, 1.0000]})

    allocation = factors.join(min_max_class.set_index('class'), on='class')
    min = allocation['min_allocation'].to_numpy()
    max = allocation['max_allocation'].to_numpy()
    ineq1 = {'type': 'ineq',
             "fun": lambda x: np.greater_equal(x, min).sum() + np.less_equal(x, max).sum() - 2 * df.shape[1]}
    eq1 = {'type': 'eq', "fun": lambda x: 1 - np.sum(x)}

    result = sp.minimize(fun=lambda x: np.std(np.dot(df, x.T), ddof=1), x0=x0, bounds=bounds, method='SLSQP',
                         options={'disp': True}, constraints=[eq1, ineq1])

    print(f"final result : {np.round(result.x,2)}, objective value: {result.fun}")
    print(f" Manual : {x_expected}, objective value: {np.std(np.dot(df, x_expected.T))}")
```

I would expect the final results to be close to "x_expected"... but that is not the case.. any ideas ?

Comment: Without going through your code, 1) are your sure `x_expected` is actually correct? 2) `minimize` may not succeed, have you checked if it converged successfully? 3) even if it converges, it may be to a local minimum only, not the one you necessarily expect.

Comment: Yes.. the objective function essentially minimises standard deviation of a series of weighted values.. the constraint is trying to limit the weighted allocation for each specific category (x,y,z for t1, t2, t3, c).. so the optimal solution should be to allocate  to whichever series gives the min standard deviation.. which in this case is "c"

Comment: Is there a better way of finding a global minimum for this sort of problem.. or should I start exploring cvxpy (not sure if that gives better convergence??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SLSQP solver failed to find the optimal value for your problem.

```
def obj(x):
    return np.std(np.dot(df, x.T), ddof=1)

def ineq(x):
    # Non-negative
    return np.greater_equal(x, min).sum() + np.less_equal(x, max).sum() - 2 * df.shape[1]

def eq(x):
    # Zero
    return 1 - np.sum(x)

result = scipy.optimize.minimize(fun=obj, x0=x0, bounds=bounds, method='SLSQP', options={'disp': True}, constraints=[eq1, ineq1])
> "Positive directional derivative for linesearch    (Exit mode 8)"
```

Therefore, inequality constraint does not hold.

```
x_opt = np.round(result.x,2)

print(f"opt.   result : {x_opt}, objective: {obj(x_opt)}, ineq: {ineq(x_opt)}, eq: {eq(x_opt)}")
print(f"manual result : {x_expected}, objective: {obj(x_expected)}, ineq: {ineq(x_expected)}, eq: {eq(x_expected)}")
```

```
opt.   result : [0.03 0.   0.   0.97], objective: 0.1554107460891942, ineq: -1, eq: 0.0
manual result : [0. 0. 0. 1.], objective: 0.15811388300841892, ineq: 0, eq: 0.0
```

Initial guess `[0, 0, 0, 0]` can help find the optimal value for your problem.

```
x0 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
bounds = ((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1))
ineq1 = {'type': 'ineq', "fun": ineq}
eq1 = {'type': 'eq', "fun": eq}

result = scipy.optimize.minimize(fun=obj, x0=x0, bounds=bounds, method='SLSQP', options={'disp': True}, constraints=[eq1, ineq1])
> Optimization terminated successfully    (Exit mode 0)

print(f"opt.   result : {x_opt}, objective: {obj(x_opt)}, ineq: {ineq(x_opt)}, eq: {eq(x_opt)}")
> opt.   result : [0. 0. 0. 1.], objective: 0.15811388300841892, ineq: 0, eq: 0.0
```

Comment: Thanks... I have run into a follow-up problem now.. changing the "max-allocation" to [0.6, 0.5, 0.1] or a host of other values results in either "iteration limit reached" or a previously encountered " Positive directional derivative for linesearch"

Comment: The result of an optimization problem is largely affected by the optimization method, parameters, and initial guess. Moreover, failures during the optimization are not rare situation. If you can make your problem as a convex one (or if your problem is already convex), convex solvers may provide better results.